# Activities not showing in Home Screen

Tags: dashboard, dashlet

When I click on CiviCRM to go to the home screen, there is a dashlet there for Activies.  It always shows none.  If I go to search activities, I see all kinds of them - why is this not updating?

Comment: What version of Civi are you using?  Does the 'Refresh Dashboard Data' link at the top right of the dashboard help?

Comment: Civicrm 4.7.  The refresh dashboard data link still results in the Activities list being empty.  It takes a second or two with the turning icon indicating it is refreshing then the result is 'none found'.

Comment: Do you see same behaviour on one of the Demo sites?

Comment: Hmm just checked a couple of the demo sites and they are fine...except there is a difference.  They are all on Drupal, not WordPress.